# How to send returned data to text edit via applescript

Tags: authentication, applescript, textedit

Im trying to make a LAN website for my family. but I can not figure out how to have the out put username and password to transfer and be stored on text edit with out textedit having to open.

this is all I have so far..

```
set theReturnedItems to (display dialog "Set Username" default answer "" buttons {"Quit","OK"} default button 2)
set my_name to the text returned of theReturnedItems
set my_pass to text returned of ¬
(display dialog "Enter password for " & ¬
    quoted form of my_name ¬
    with title ¬
    "Pass Word" with icon stop ¬
    default answer ¬
    "" buttons {"Continue…"} ¬
    default button 1 ¬
    giving up after 30000 with hidden answer)
```

Comment: Are you wanting to save the output to a text file?

Comment: I assume you mean TextEdit.app. You cannot store text on it. It is an application that reads and displays the contents of text files. As adamh asks if  you are wanting to write to a text file on your Hard disk, then this is very very easy. But adjust your question so people do not ignore your question or assume what you mean.